# How to regenerate my corrupted GUI form?

Tags: java, forms, user-interface, netbeans

Hej all,

Yesterday before finishing my work I build up my project in NetBeans and saved it. Today when I got up and open project, I got a warning like this: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/812/problemez.png/.

What can I do in order to recover my GUI form? now my GUI is just in read-only mode, what is totally useless ...

Thanks!

### Michal.

OK I have done it finally. For those of you who would find similar problem:
1. Create new GUI JFrame form in the same project.
2. Copy all the compoments from the previous JFRame form(in read-only mode) into the new one 
3. There will be automatically created new code, now correctly.
4. Just copy all your code into the new form code.

Comment: You should add the solution as an answer and mark it as accepted. This way other users will know there is a solution.

Comment: The proper answer to this question is: restore the missing comments by relying on your code versioning system and a diff tool. Netbeans may randomly decide to strip those for some reason.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For those of you who would find similar problem:

1. Create new GUI `JFrame` form in the same project.
2. Copy all the components from the previous `JFrame` form(in read-only mode) into the new one
3. There will be automatically created new code for new form.
4. Just copy all your code (your methods) into the new form code.

Answer (score 4):

most likely you removed the parts that say 'generated code here'

(the lines look like this:

```
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
private void initComponents() {
...
}// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents
```

recreate them.
And be aware that there are more than just the ones for initComponents.

Comment: I have recreated them, but still nothing changed.

Comment: have you recreated the end parts as well? (I will add them to my post next, sorry i forgot.)

Comment: yes, I did. Btw I have solved it already, check me question. I have edited it. :)

Comment: cool. please add your solution as an answer and mark it as the correct one so this question appears as solved.

Comment: I have already done it, but I am allowed to mark it as correct not earlier than in 17 hours ...

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the Form object in Navigator, and click Reload form.

[netbeans-screencapture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FbOw.png)

Answer (score 0):

create new `Jframe`and in `Jframe Navigator` of NetBeans copy all component in previous `Jframe`to new `Jframe`

Answer (score 0):

Editing the .java to add the missing NetBeans comments, as suggested by Angelo Fuchs seems to be easier than creating a new frame.

Here is how to "repair" the variable declaration bloc and the generated event methods:

```
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Variables declaration - do not modify ">
// Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
private JPanel jPanelChart;
private JSlider jSliderThickness;
// End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
//</editor-fold>
```

and

```
    private void jSliderThicknessStateChanged(ChangeEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jSliderThicknessStateChanged
    stroke = jSliderThickness.getValue() * 0.01f;
    renderer.setSeriesStroke(0, new BasicStroke(stroke));
}//GEN-LAST:event_jSliderThicknessStateChanged
```